# SQL Oracle repeated results when using OR

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to match names in DS to ids in A, and they can be connected only through DA which is basically customer id and item id. I also need to show item that has no record of purchase.

I have tried using both conditions separately, 
Part A

```
SELECT DS.name,A.id
FROM DS,
A,
DA
WHERE DS.id=DA.id AND 
A.id=DA.id;
```

Part B

```
SELECT name
FROM DS,
WHERE DS.id NOT IN (
SELECT id FROM DA);
```

Then when I use the following code

```
SELECT DS.name,A.id
FROM DS,
A,
DA
WHERE (DS.id=DA.id AND 
A.id=DA.id) OR 
DS.id NOT IN (
SELECT id FROM DA);
```

Part A returns 4077 results and part B returns 820, but the final code gave me 140000 before I terminated it.
I know I can get rid of them by using DISTINCT but I want to know the reason for this and how to actually avoid this kind of things from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `join` and `left outer join`:

```
SELECT DS.name,A.id
FROM DA join 
A on A.id=DA.id
left outer join DA on DS.id=DA.id
```

That should give you the correct result.

In your query you get a cross product of all records.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query

```
    select TABA.DS_NAME,TABA.A_ID
    from 
    (SELECT DS.name as Ds_Name,A.id as A_ID
    FROM DS,
    A,
    DA
    WHERE DS.id=DA.id AND 
    A.id=DA.id)as TABA join 
    (SELECT name,id
    FROM DS,
    WHERE DS.id NOT IN(
    SELECT id FROM DA))as TABB
    on TABA.A_ID = TABB.id
```

Regards.